# How to Add a new field in database using XMLDB in moodle

Tags: php, xml, moodle

I am facing a problem.I am not able to upgrade database in moodle. I created a new field in moodle using xmldb and created upgrade.php and write the modified code there.But it doesn't upgrade database.Upgraded code contain version like this XXXXXXXXXX.What to write here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XXXXXXX is where you put the new version number for your plugin.

So, using today's date as an example, edit your plugin's version.php, to set the version number to 2014092900 (29th Sept 2014, version 00), then put the same version number in your plugin's upgrade.php script, instead of the the 'XXXXXXXX' bit (I'm assuming you've already created the function 'xmldb_MYPLUGINTYPE_MYPLUGINNAME_upgrade($olversion = 0)' to put this upgrade code in).

Comment: yes, i have write xmldb_activitysetmodule_upgrade($oldversion=0).is it right?

Comment: So you should have: function xmldb_activitysetmodule_upgrade($oldversion = 0) { 
global $DB; 
$dbman = $DB->get_manager(); 
// Next you should have your DB upgrade code
return true;
}
Update your version number in version.php and then your upgrade should run.